# Nested Repeater not able to access in server side code

Tags: asp.net, repeater

In the repeater, I have a stores repeater which displays several different stores. Inside of that repeater, I have a nested repeater that should display all departments for those store. I am not sure why, but in my code-behind, I am unable to access the nested repeater. Can someone point out the problem with my front-end code. Thanks in advance.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="r_store" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <br><b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StoreName") %></b>
        <asp:Repeater ID="r_dept" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <br><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DepartmentName") %> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: "in my code-behind, I am unable to access the nested repeater" perhaps showing us the code where you have the problem would enable us to help you?

Comment: Dave Parsons, it is as you would access any repeater using r_dept.DataSource =, here I can see my r_store repeater, but not the nested one.

Comment: You can use `(Repeater) e.Item.FindControl("r_dept")` in `r_store.ItemDataBound`. You cannot access the nested repeater directly since it's sitting in a different `NamingContainer` as the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.net nested controls cannot be automatically found. This is because simply searching for the nested repeater via say it's ID is ambiguous.

What you need to do is handle the original Repeaters ItemDataBound event and then call FindControl to get your nested Repeater. I don't have VS on this computer, but something like this:

```
Sub r_store_ItemDataBound(Sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or _
            (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
    dim innerRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("r_dept")
    'now work with the innerRepeater
  end if
End Sub
```

Comment: The data source with departments is shared with the datasource for stores. Do you know how I could set this in the server side?

Comment: if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem){
                Repeater innerRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("r_dept");
                innerRepeater.DataSource = LoadDepartments();                   
                innerRepeater.DataBind();   
            }

Comment: @jpavlov Your 2nd comment looks like the way. It's the same as doing the other repeater from the code behind.